# Add a row in a template table Flask with a specificy row id

Tags: javascript, templates, flask

this is a part of my template:

```
<form method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <table id="myTable">
                <tr class="heading">
                    <td>
                        Item
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        Price
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <div id="itemstable">
                    {% if items|length > 0 %}
                        {% for item in items %}
                            <tr class="item">
                                <td>
                                    <input id="item-{{ item.id }}" name="description-{{ item.id }}" required="" type="text" value="{{ item.description }}" >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input  id="item-{{ item.id }}" name="amount-{{ item.id }}" required="" type="number" min="0"  value="{{ item.amount }}" onchange="sumamount();">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <tr class="item">
                            <div>
                            <td>
                                <input id="item-{{ items|length }}" name="description-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="{{form.description}}">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="item-{{ items|length }}" name="amount-{{ items|length }}" required="" type="text" value="{{form.amount}}" onchange="sumamount();">
                            </td>
                                </div>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr class="total">
                    <div>
                    <td>
                        Total:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input id="total" type="text" value="0"readonly>
                    </td>
                        </div>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button id="add" onclick="addLineItem(event)">Add Item</button>
            <div>
</form>
    <script>

// function to add a row in table
    let currMax = {{ items|length }} + 1;
    function addLineItem(e){
        var lineItem = "<tr class='item'> <td> <input id='item-"+currMax+"' name='description-"+currMax+"' required='' type='text' value=''></td> <td> <input id='item-"+currMax+"' name='amount-"+currMax+"' required='' type='text' value=''></td> </tr>";
        currMax++;
        document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML += lineItem;
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Still on page!");
    }
    function sumamount(){
        sum=0;
        $("input[name^='amount-']").each(function(){
            sum+=Number($(this).val());
        });
        $("#total").val(sum);
    }
</script>
```

I create a button which add a row (function addLineItem(e)).
But when I submit my form. In the request this added row is not in the request and my second issue is that this new row is not taking into account in my js function sumamount() (value is till 0 unless I fill something in amount field.

thanks for help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way. just move my  up before my add button and suprisingly, it works.